# Is there a way to add dependency restrictions to packages in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

It would be useful to add restrictions between packages on a Bazel workspace. Something like "packages tagged as 'library' may not depend on packages tagged as 'app'"

I remember hearing that this was a featured supported by Blaze originally but looking at the documentation https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html nothing like it seems to be mentioned anywhere.

Is it possible to do something like this with Bazel?

Comment: What would the use case of this? Individual rules can determine if they can depend on other rule classes based on their name, or the providers they expose.

Comment: I'm mostly thinking of using this kind of rules to help while splitting a monolithic repository into multiple interconnected packages.

As in, adding rules that would forbid a library from importing stuff from an end application package as a way to signal "If you're trying to use some code from the end app, you should probably pull that code out to a separate library"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bazel's `visibility` label is used to restrict access to packages. Of interest to you might be the 'package_group' flavor.

Taken from https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html:

```
The visibility attribute on a rule controls whether the rule can be used by other packages. Rules are always visible to other rules declared in the same package.

There are five forms (and one temporary form) a visibility label can take:

["//visibility:public"]: Anyone can use this rule.
["//visibility:private"]: Only rules in this package can use this rule. Rules in javatests/foo/bar can always use rules in java/foo/bar.
["//some/package:__pkg__", "//other/package:__pkg__"]: Only rules in some/package and other/package (defined in some/package/BUILD and other/package/BUILD) have access to this rule. Note that sub-packages do not have access to the rule; for example, //some/package/foo:bar or //other/package/testing:bla wouldn't have access. __pkg__ is a special target and must be used verbatim. It represents all of the rules in the package.
["//project:__subpackages__", "//other:__subpackages__"]: Only rules in packages project or other or in one of their sub-packages have access to this rule. For example, //project:rule, //project/library:lib or //other/testing/internal:munge are allowed to depend on this rule (but not //independent:evil)
["//some/package:my_package_group"]: A package group is a named set of package names. Package groups can also grant access rights to entire subtrees, e.g.//myproj/....
The visibility specifications of //visibility:public and //visibility:private can not be combined with any other visibility specifications. A visibility specification may contain a combination of package labels (i.e. //foo:__pkg__) and package_groups.

If a rule does specify the visibility attribute, that specification overrides any default_visibility attribute of the package statement in the BUILD file containing the rule.

Otherwise, if a rule does not specify the visibility attribute, the default_visibility of the package is used (except for exports_files).

Otherwise, if the default_visibility for the package is not specified, //visibility:private is used.

Example:

File //frobber/bin/BUILD:

# This rule is visible to everyone
cc_binary(
    name = "executable",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":library"],
)

# This rule is visible only to rules declared in the same package
cc_library(
    name = "library",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)

# This rule is visible to rules in package //object and //noun
cc_library(
    name = "subject",
    visibility = [
        "//noun:__pkg__",
        "//object:__pkg__",
    ],
)

# See package group "//frobber:friends" (below) for who can
# access this rule.
cc_library(
    name = "thingy",
    visibility = ["//frobber:friends"],
)
File //frobber/BUILD:

# This is the package group declaration to which rule
# //frobber/bin:thingy refers.
#
# Our friends are packages //frobber, //fribber and any
# subpackage of //fribber.
package_group(
    name = "friends",
    packages = [
        "//fribber/...",
        "//frobber",
    ],
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, my Google-fu chops failed me. Thank you!